# ZendDeveloperTools creates git submodule using composer and cannot add to git repo

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-studio

When I add the composer repo `ZendDeveloperTools` it creates a git submodule and then i cannot commit it. how do i handle adding this to my application github account?

[Zend Tools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools)

Comment: Please explain how you add the repository. Maybe show the commands you are executing. Are you adding the repo using Git and not by fetching it via Composer?

Comment: its a zend studio issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with committing submodules using Zend Studio. If you hop on the commandline you can commit but it seems impossible to commit in Zend Studio.